# Access Wordpress Core from plugin file (globals like: $menu, $submenu, etc.)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently developing a plugin for Wordpress. The plugin is located at: `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/`.

Inside my plugin folder, I have created a file named `results.php`, which is used by some jQuery-code to gather specific information.

The top of `results.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;

require(BASE_PATH . 'wp-load.php');
    global $menu, $submenu;

    echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>';

    foreach($menu as $key => $item) {
        // rest of the code...
        // etc
```

But sadly this doesn't work.

In above example I need to fetch data from the global array `$menu` and `$submenu`, which perfectly works at my plugins settings page (loaded by `add_submenu_page`).

Does anybody of you know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items

Answer (score 0):

Wow - well, I seemed to have found the solution:

`results.php`:

```
<?php
    $root = dirname( __FILE__ );
    $root = explode('wp-content', $root);
    $root = $root[0] . 'wp-admin/admin.php';
    require_once($root);

        echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>';

        foreach($menu as $key => $item) {
            // rest of the code...
            // etc
```

So - it works.

Any feedback for above solution? (compatibility-wise). It seems too simple to me.